# Restore pack value from hex string

Tags: perl, binary, data-conversion, binary-data, pack

If I have a hex value produced with e.g.

```
my $hex = sprintf "%v02X", $packed_output
```

and the `$packed_output` is the result of `pack` over a series of numbers i.e.

```
my $packed_output = pack "L>*", map { $_->[0] << 16 | $_->[1] } @array;
```

is there a way from that `$ hex` string to get back the `$packed_output`?

Answer (score 4):

One approach: Split the string up on period, and convert all the hex-string bytes back to numbers with `hex`, and then pack them all back together again:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my $packed_output = pack "L>*", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
my $hex = sprintf "%v02X", $packed_output;
# $hex is
# 00.00.00.01.00.00.00.02.00.00.00.03.00.00.00.04.00.00.00.05.00.00.00.06

my $binary = pack "(h2)*", map(hex, split(/\./, $hex));

$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper($packed_output, $binary);
# Outputs
# $VAR1 = "\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\6";
# $VAR2 = "\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\6";
```

It sounds like what you're *really* after is an easy way to have a round-trip conversion between binary and textual data, though. Using `sprintf` to make a hex vector string like the above is not it.

Perl comes with support for industry-standard [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and the older [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) (Which is built in via `pack` and `unpack`, instead of a core module). Examples:

``````perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use feature qw/say/;

my $packed_output = pack "L>*", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;

# Base64
my $base64 = encode_base64($packed_output, "");
print $base64; # AAAAAQAAAAIAAAADAAAABAAAAAUAAAAG
my $decoded_b64 = decode_base64($base64);
say "It's a match!" if $packed_output eq $decoded_b64;

# uuencode
my $uuencoded = pack "u", $packed_output;
print $uuencoded; # 8`````0````(````#````!`````4````&
my ($decoded_uu) = unpack "u", $uuencoded;
say "Another match!" if $packed_output eq $decoded_uu;
``````

Comment: 1) Besides hex is there any other way to convert the output of pack in this case that is more readily converted back? E.g. series of decimals or something else? 2) What is `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1`?

Comment: @Jim [Base64 encoding](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME::Base64) comes to mind, or uuencode (using [pack and unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut#Uuencoding)) And see https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods

Comment: Aside: The wikipedia article on uuencoding includes perl code to decode Base64 data by first converting it to uuencode and then using `unpack`. I don't know if I should be concerned or impressed by the person who came up with that scheme.

Comment: @Jim base64 encoding is indeed optimal for storing binary data as ASCII. UU encoding is an ancient, less optimal alternative. You should definitely not use both base64 encoding and UU encoding.

Comment: Simpler/faster: `my $packed_output = pack "H*", $hex =~ s/\.//gr;`

Comment: @ikegami: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548713/file-with-two-columns-the-second-containing-binary-value-and-sortable-by-first-c to store the binary value